# System.arraycopy throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, mergesort

Why does `System.arraycopy()` throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? I am trying to write mergeSort(it's not final version, firstly I want that current alghorithm work with these data).

```
package Procedural.Intro;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Сергей on 28.06.2015.
 */
public class MergerSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] initial;
        int [] initial2;


        initial = new int [] {1, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        initial2 = new int [] {2, 4, 9, 11, 121};



        System.out.println("Array1 initial: " + Arrays.toString(initial));
        System.out.println("Array2 initial: " + Arrays.toString(initial2));


        System.out.println("Array result: " + Arrays.toString(MergerSort.mergerSort(initial, initial2)));



    }
       private static int [] mergerSort(int[] left, int[] right) {

            int [] result = new int[left.length + right.length];
            int leftIndex = 0;
           int rightIndex = 0;
          while( leftIndex + rightIndex < result.length) {

               if(left[leftIndex] > right[rightIndex]) {
                   result[leftIndex + rightIndex] = right[rightIndex++];
               }
               else {
                   result[leftIndex + rightIndex] = left[leftIndex++];
               }
               if(leftIndex == left.length) {

                 System.arraycopy(right, right[rightIndex],  result, leftIndex + rightIndex, result.length - (leftIndex + rightIndex));
                   break;
               }
               if(rightIndex == right.length) {
                   System.arraycopy(left, left[leftIndex],  result, leftIndex + rightIndex, result.length - ( leftIndex + rightIndex));
                   break;
               }
           }

         return result;
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Your debugger may be helpful.

Comment: Do you know what an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is?

Comment: yes I know what is  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException; yes I use my IDE

Comment: Not completely sure what you're trying to do. Try this:  `String[] both = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b)).toArray(String[]::new);` then `Arrays.sort(both);`

Comment: I want to understand why do I have this exception, I don't need another way of solution this task

Comment: The most frequent issue is that one of the indices or lengths is off by 1. The details of the exception should help you find out which one.

Comment: If you know what the exception means, then you should know why this is happening. Use your debugger and inspect the values you're passing into `arraycopy` at runtime and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the documentation to [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29), it expects as the second argument an **index** into the array. However, you have there a **value** from your array. So most probably you wanted to write

```
System.arraycopy(right, rightIndex, ...
```

instead of

```
System.arraycopy(right, right[rightIndex], ...
```

The same for your second call of `System.arraycopy`

Comment: Thanks a lot) I should be more attentive))

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting that the last index is not the array length, it's the array length - 1. You forgot to subtract one from the last parameter in your `System.arraycopy`
You have `result.length - (leftIndex + rightIndex)` where it should be 
`result.length - (leftIndex + rightIndex) - 1`

Comment: sorry, please, can you explain why it should be array length - 1? in javadoc it's said that 5 parameter it's length - the number of array elements to be copied. so, in my case I should copy 3 elements(in array right numbers 9, 11,121)